# Why "surface evaporation conditions" are the special case of the Robin's boundary condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In a book about ecological modelling (Soetaert K, Herman P M J. A practical guide to ecological modelling: using R as a simulation platform[M]. Springer Science & Business Media, 2008.), the authors showed an example about Robin's condition. It is called a special case of it ("surface evaporation conditions"). This part of the book can be seen in Fig.1.

However, I cannot see what's the similarity between Equation(3.34) and Equation(3.33). I mean, in Equation(3.34), there is no "concentration gradient" term. Besides, the equation has a "reference concentration" term, which is also different from Equation(3.33).

Could someone tell me why Equation(3.34) is a "special case" of Equation(3.33)?

[image: Fig.1].

Comment: I think that equation is a definition for $\beta$ in the special case of surface evaporation conditions, which is then substituted in the RHS of 3.33

Comment: @whpowell96 That makes sense. So $\beta$ needs not be a parameter that excludes the variable "C"?

Comment: It looks like for this special case, the perscribed flux $\beta$ is given by the difference between $C$ and the reference concentration $C_s$, which is relatively common